# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in scikit-learn Dictionary Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I have written a code for Dictionary Learning. It is working fine for 100 Images but if I use 200 Images to learn Dictionary I am getting Segment fault error .

Here is my code =>

```
from time import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

from sklearn.decomposition import MiniBatchDictionaryLearning
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches_2d
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import reconstruct_from_patches_2d

from sklearn.utils.fixes import sp_version
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image

from scipy import ndimage

from skimage import color
from skimage import io

from PIL import Image

from sklearn.decomposition import SparseCoder
from sklearn.decomposition import sparse_encode

#from skimage import data,restoration
from scipy.misc import imfilter, imread
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2


from skimage import data, img_as_float


from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage import feature

from scipy.misc import imsave


from os import listdir

patch_size = (8,8)
reshape_size = (512,512)

c = np.asarray(Image.open('test/ILSVRC2012_test_00016644.JPEG').resize((512,512), Image.ANTIALIAS))

data = extract_patches_2d(c,(8,8))


total_img = 0

for f in listdir('test/'):
    if f.endswith('.JPEG') and f.startswith('I'):
        if (total_img <= 200):      
            total_img = total_img + 1
            print(f)
            print('data shape : ',data.shape)
            print('total file : ',total_img)

            A = np.asarray(Image.open('test/'+f).resize(reshape_size, Image.ANTIALIAS))
            X =  extract_patches_2d(A,patch_size)
            data = np.append(data,X,axis=0)
            print('patch shape',X.shape)
        else:
            break
print('Total number of Image : ',total_img)

print('Total Patches : ',data.shape)                   
print('total size of the array : ',data.nbytes)

n0 = np.asarray(Image.open('data2/004.jpg').resize((512,512), Image.ANTIALIAS))


n0 = n0 / 255



height, width, channel = n0.shape


n0 = n0 + 0.075 * np.random.randn(height, width,3)

n0 = n0 * 255

imsave('gray.png',n0)




patchsize = (8,8)
t0 = time()




data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], -1)

print('Extract patch shape :',data.shape)

data = data - np.mean(data, axis=0)
data = data / np.std(data, axis=0)

t1 = time()
print('Total time : ',round((t1-t0),2),' sec')

print('Learning the dictionary ....')

t2 = time()
n_iter = 5000

dico = MiniBatchDictionaryLearning(n_components=100,alpha=3,n_iter=n_iter)

V = dico.fit(data).components_
print('Dic shape : ',V.shape)
t3 = time()
print('No of iteration : ',n_iter)
print('Total time taken for Dictionary learning : ',round((t3-t2),2),' sec')
```

I have sufficient RAM around 500GB. But I am getting segment fault error.
How do I Fix this??

Comment: Please execute your python script under `gdb` and provide the C backtraces to see where it crashes. https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Comment: okk, After doing this I will reply you . Thanks,

Comment: "RAM around 500GB" or maybe storage around 500GB

Comment: no, I am doing it in high performance computer @VivekKumar

Comment: because I have to store all patches in ram that is why my cllg provide me such type of config. @VivekKumar

Comment: Oh Ohk. My bad. Sorry

Comment: @languitar I have used gdb .. and getting this one "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff3059f50 in ATL_dJIK0x0x48NN0x0x0_aX_bX () from /usr/lib/libblas.so.3". What is the meaning of this??