# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error scikit learn cosine similarity on large sparse matrix (86196 X 15497)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, segmentation-fault, cosine-similarity

I ran the code below on an input matrix of dimensions 86196 x 15497 (size is 10.3 GB). It is a mostly sparse matrix. I am using sklearn.metircs.pairwise cosine similarity.

I am able to run a 43098 x 15497 input matrix (resultant cosine similarity output matrix is 13.8 GB and dimensions of 43098 x 43098) without issue. However when attempting the 86196 x 15497 input matrix I am getting a "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" error. This is on a Google Compute instance (16 vCPUs, 128 GB RAM).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# df is TFIDF calculations on data set of features
df = pd.read_csv('/path...')

df_piv = pd.pivot(full, index='individuals', columns='features', values='TFIDF')

df_piv.fillna(0, inplace=True)

cm = cosine_similarity(df_piv)
```

I also tried the input as a numpy.ndarray instead of a pandas.core.frame.dataframe by doing "df_piv.values" and still got the error.

Here is the top line of the C stack trace:

```
Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5f86e29 in dgemm_otcopy_HASWELL () from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packag
es/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-5bebc122.3.13.dev.so
```

I am not thinking the issue is a memory problem. I did the C stack trace using gdb and I am wondering if the issue is with a 3rd party package (i.e. numpy or sklearn). Plus, I expect the resultant cosine similarity matrix to be 55.4 GB.

I have the C stack trace copied and saved if I need to report an issue to numpy/sklearn, but wanted to ask if anyone sees what I am doing wrong, or has an alternative approach to my implementation?

I looked at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115635/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-scikit-learn-dictionary-learning) and the user didn't get a response after running the C stack trace.

Python version 3.8.5

sklearn version 0.24.1

numpy version 1.20.1

pandas version 1.2.2

**UPDATE**:

Below is the full traceback from the C stack trace report:

```
Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5f86e29 in dgemm_otcopy_HASWELL () from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packag
es/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-5bebc122.3.13.dev.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5f86e29 in dgemm_otcopy_HASWELL ()
   from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp
-r0-5bebc122.3.13.dev.so
#1  0x00007ffff5311766 in inner_thread ()
   from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp
-r0-5bebc122.3.13.dev.so
#2  0x00007ffff5432635 in exec_blas ()
   from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp
-r0-5bebc122.3.13.dev.so
#3  0x00007ffff5312113 in dsyrk_thread_LN ()
   from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp
-r0-5bebc122.3.13.dev.so
#4  0x00007ffff5222ea8 in cblas_dsyrk ()
   from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblasp
-r0-5bebc122.3.13.dev.so
#5  0x00007ffff7314e76 in DOUBLE_matmul_matrixmatrix.constprop.6 ()
   from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-
x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#6  0x00007ffff73191fb in DOUBLE_matmul ()
   from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-
x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#7  0x00007ffff732a77e in PyUFunc_GenericFunction_int ()
   from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-
x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#8  0x00007ffff732acb1 in ufunc_generic_call ()
   from /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-
x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#9  0x00000000005f46d6 in _PyObject_MakeTpCall (callable=<numpy.ufunc at remote 0x7ffff7683a90>,
    args=<optimized out>, nargs=<optimized out>, keywords=<optimized out>)
    at ../Include/internal/pycore_pyerrors.h:13
#10 0x00000000005f4de5 in _PyObject_Vectorcall (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=2, args=0x7fffffffd5b0,
    callable=<numpy.ufunc at remote 0x7ffff7683a90>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:125
#11 _PyObject_Vectorcall (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=2, args=0x7fffffffd5b0,
    callable=<numpy.ufunc at remote 0x7ffff7683a90>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:115
#12 _PyObject_FastCall (nargs=2, args=0x7fffffffd5b0,
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--<RET>
    func=<numpy.ufunc at remote 0x7ffff7683a90>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:147
#13 object_vacall (base=<optimized out>, callable=<numpy.ufunc at remote 0x7ffff7683a90>,
    vargs=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/call.c:1186
#14 0x00000000005f4f65 in PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs (callable=<optimized out>)
    at ../Objects/call.c:1259
#15 0x000000000050e327 in binary_op1 (v=<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579b10>,
    w=<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579c90>, op_slot=<optimized out>)
    at ../Objects/abstract.c:808
#16 0x000000000061884a in binary_op (v=<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579b10>,
    w=<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579c90>, op_slot=272, op_name=0x6d858f "@")
    at ../Objects/abstract.c:837
#17 0x00000000004b907e in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:1490
#18 0x000000000056955a in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0,
    f=Frame 0x7fff99274840, for file /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/uti
ls/extmath.py, line 152, in safe_sparse_dot (a=<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579b10>, b=<numpy.
ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579c90>, dense_output=True)) at ../Python/ceval.c:741
#19 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (_co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>,
    locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>,
    kwnames=<optimized out>, kwargs=0x7fff992851a0, kwcount=<optimized out>, kwstep=1, defs=0x0,
    defcount=0, kwdefs={'dense_output': False}, closure=0x0, name='safe_sparse_dot',
    qualname='safe_sparse_dot') at ../Python/ceval.c:4298
#20 0x00000000005f7323 in _PyFunction_Vectorcall (func=<optimized out>, stack=0x7fff99285190,
    nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/call.c:435
#21 0x00000000005f3d42 in PyVectorcall_Call (kwargs=<optimized out>, tuple=<optimized out>,
    callable=<function at remote 0x7fff9aa56d30>) at ../Objects/call.c:1296
#22 PyObject_Call (callable=<function at remote 0x7fff9aa56d30>, args=<optimized out>,
    kwargs=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/call.c:227
#23 0x000000000056ca92 in do_call_core (kwdict={'dense_output': True},
    callargs=(<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579b10>, <numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579c90>),
 func=<function at remote 0x7fff9aa56d30>, tstate=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:5010
#24 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3559
#25 0x000000000056955a in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0,
    f=Frame 0x7fffc5d1a240, for file /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/uti
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--<RET>
ls/validation.py, line 63, in inner_f (args=(<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579b10>, <numpy.ndar
ray at remote 0x7fff97579c90>), kwargs={'dense_output': True}, extra_args=0))
    at ../Python/ceval.c:741
#26 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (_co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>,
    locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>,
    kwnames=<optimized out>, kwargs=0x7fff9926ef10, kwcount=<optimized out>, kwstep=1, defs=0x0,
    defcount=0, kwdefs=0x0,
    closure=(<cell at remote 0x7fff9ab059d0>, <cell at remote 0x7fff9ab05910>, <cell at remote 0x7
fff9ab05a00>, <cell at remote 0x7fff9ab05a60>, <cell at remote 0x7fff9ab05070>),
    name='safe_sparse_dot', qualname='safe_sparse_dot') at ../Python/ceval.c:4298
#27 0x00000000005f7323 in _PyFunction_Vectorcall (func=<optimized out>, stack=0x7fff9926ef00,
    nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/call.c:435
#28 0x000000000056c451 in _PyObject_Vectorcall (kwnames=('dense_output',),
    nargsf=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, callable=<function at remote 0x7fff9aa56e50>)
    at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:127
#29 call_function (kwnames=('dense_output',), oparg=<optimized out>,
    pp_stack=<synthetic pointer>, tstate=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4963
#30 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3515
#31 0x000000000056955a in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0,
    f=Frame 0x7fff9926ed60, for file /home/gndumbri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/met
rics/pairwise.py, line 1444, in cosine_similarity (X=<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579ab0>, Y=<
numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579ab0>, dense_output=True, X_normalized=<numpy.ndarray at remote
0x7fff97579b10>, Y_normalized=<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x7fff97579b10>)) at ../Python/ceval.c:741
#32 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (_co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>,
    locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>,
    kwnames=<optimized out>, kwargs=0x7ffff77ef7c0, kwcount=<optimized out>, kwstep=1,
    defs=0x7fff9ac78ed8, defcount=2, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x0, name='cosine_similarity',
    qualname='cosine_similarity') at ../Python/ceval.c:4298
#33 0x00000000005f7323 in _PyFunction_Vectorcall (func=<optimized out>, stack=0x7ffff77ef7b8,
    nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/call.c:435
#34 0x000000000056b26e in _PyObject_Vectorcall (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=<optimized out>,
    args=0x7ffff77ef7b8, callable=<function at remote 0x7fff9a0d08b0>)
    at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:127
#35 call_function (kwnames=0x0, oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=<synthetic pointer>,
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--<RET>
    tstate=0x962400) at ../Python/ceval.c:4963
#36 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3500
#37 0x000000000056955a in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0,
    f=Frame 0x7ffff77ef640, for file cos_sim.py, line 46, in <module> ())
    at ../Python/ceval.c:741
#38 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (_co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>,
    locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>,
    kwnames=<optimized out>, kwargs=0x0, kwcount=<optimized out>, kwstep=2, defs=0x0,
    defcount=0, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x0, name=0x0, qualname=0x0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4298
#39 0x000000000068c4a7 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (closure=0x0, kwdefs=0x0, defcount=0, defs=0x0,
    kwcount=0, kws=0x0, argcount=0, args=0x0, locals=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>,
    _co=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4327
#40 PyEval_EvalCode (co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:718
#41 0x000000000067bc91 in run_eval_code_obj (co=0x7ffff777a920,
    globals={'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <SourceFi
leLoader(name='__main__', path='cos_sim.py') at remote 0x7ffff7800550>, '__spec__': None, '__annot
ations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module at remote 0x7ffff787b0e0>, '__file__': 'cos_sim.py', '__cac
hed__': None, 'time': <module at remote 0x7ffff7860b30>, 'pd': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e50e0>,
'np': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e5810>, 'cosine_similarity': <function at remote 0x7fff9a0d08b0>,
 'path_A': '/home/gndumbri/diag.csv', 'calc_tfidf': <function at remote 0x7ffff78421f0>, 'start':
<float at remote 0x7fff9a0be250>, 'full': <DataFrame(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<BlockManager at remote 0
x7fff95b30ac0>, _item_cache={'TOTL_BENE_CNT': <Series(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<SingleBlockManager at r
emote 0x7fff99c23a00>, _item_cache={}, _attrs={}, _flags=<Flags(_allows_duplicate_labels=True, _ob
j=<weakref at remote 0x7fff992d81d0>) at remote 0x7fff9ac32970>, _name='TOTL_BENE_CNT', _index=<Ra
ngeIndex(_range=<range at remote 0x7ffff78007e0>, _name=...(truncated),
    locals={'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <SourceFil
eLoader(name='__main__', path='cos_sim.py') at remote 0x7ffff7800550>, '__spec__': None, '__annota
tions__': {}, '__builtins__': <module at remote 0x7ffff787b0e0>, '__file__': 'cos_sim.py', '__cach
ed__': None, 'time': <module at remote 0x7ffff7860b30>, 'pd': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e50e0>, '
np': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e5810>, 'cosine_similarity': <function at remote 0x7fff9a0d08b0>,
'path_A': '/home/gndumbri/diag.csv', 'calc_tfidf': <function at remote 0x7ffff78421f0>, 'start': <
float at remote 0x7fff9a0be250>, 'full': <DataFrame(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<BlockManager at remote 0x
7fff95b30ac0>, _item_cache={'TOTL_BENE_CNT': <Series(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<SingleBlockManager at re
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--<RET>
mote 0x7fff99c23a00>, _item_cache={}, _attrs={}, _flags=<Flags(_allows_duplicate_labels=True, _obj
=<weakref at remote 0x7fff992d81d0>) at remote 0x7fff9ac32970>, _name='TOTL_BENE_CNT', _index=<Ran
geIndex(_range=<range at remote 0x7ffff78007e0>, _name=...(truncated))
    at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1125
#42 0x000000000067bd0f in run_mod (mod=<optimized out>, filename=<optimized out>,
    globals={'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <SourceFi
leLoader(name='__main__', path='cos_sim.py') at remote 0x7ffff7800550>, '__spec__': None, '__annot
ations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module at remote 0x7ffff787b0e0>, '__file__': 'cos_sim.py', '__cac
hed__': None, 'time': <module at remote 0x7ffff7860b30>, 'pd': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e50e0>,
'np': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e5810>, 'cosine_similarity': <function at remote 0x7fff9a0d08b0>,
 'path_A': '/home/gndumbri/diag.csv', 'calc_tfidf': <function at remote 0x7ffff78421f0>, 'start':
<float at remote 0x7fff9a0be250>, 'full': <DataFrame(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<BlockManager at remote 0
x7fff95b30ac0>, _item_cache={'TOTL_BENE_CNT': <Series(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<SingleBlockManager at r
emote 0x7fff99c23a00>, _item_cache={}, _attrs={}, _flags=<Flags(_allows_duplicate_labels=True, _ob
j=<weakref at remote 0x7fff992d81d0>) at remote 0x7fff9ac32970>, _name='TOTL_BENE_CNT', _index=<Ra
ngeIndex(_range=<range at remote 0x7ffff78007e0>, _name=...(truncated),
    locals={'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <SourceFil
eLoader(name='__main__', path='cos_sim.py') at remote 0x7ffff7800550>, '__spec__': None, '__annota
tions__': {}, '__builtins__': <module at remote 0x7ffff787b0e0>, '__file__': 'cos_sim.py', '__cach
ed__': None, 'time': <module at remote 0x7ffff7860b30>, 'pd': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e50e0>, '
np': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e5810>, 'cosine_similarity': <function at remote 0x7fff9a0d08b0>,
'path_A': '/home/gndumbri/diag.csv', 'calc_tfidf': <function at remote 0x7ffff78421f0>, 'start': <
float at remote 0x7fff9a0be250>, 'full': <DataFrame(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<BlockManager at remote 0x
7fff95b30ac0>, _item_cache={'TOTL_BENE_CNT': <Series(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<SingleBlockManager at re
mote 0x7fff99c23a00>, _item_cache={}, _attrs={}, _flags=<Flags(_allows_duplicate_labels=True, _obj
=<weakref at remote 0x7fff992d81d0>) at remote 0x7fff9ac32970>, _name='TOTL_BENE_CNT', _index=<Ran
geIndex(_range=<range at remote 0x7ffff78007e0>, _name=...(truncated), flags=<optimized out>,
    arena=<optimized out>) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1147
#43 0x000000000067bdcb in PyRun_FileExFlags (fp=0x95f340, filename_str=<optimized out>,
    start=<optimized out>,
    globals={'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <SourceFi
leLoader(name='__main__', path='cos_sim.py') at remote 0x7ffff7800550>, '__spec__': None, '__annot
ations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module at remote 0x7ffff787b0e0>, '__file__': 'cos_sim.py', '__cac
hed__': None, 'time': <module at remote 0x7ffff7860b30>, 'pd': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e50e0>,
'np': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e5810>, 'cosine_similarity': <function at remote 0x7fff9a0d08b0>,
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--<RET>
 'path_A': '/home/gndumbri/diag.csv', 'calc_tfidf': <function at remote 0x7ffff78421f0>, 'start':
<float at remote 0x7fff9a0be250>, 'full': <DataFrame(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<BlockManager at remote 0
x7fff95b30ac0>, _item_cache={'TOTL_BENE_CNT': <Series(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<SingleBlockManager at r
emote 0x7fff99c23a00>, _item_cache={}, _attrs={}, _flags=<Flags(_allows_duplicate_labels=True, _ob
j=<weakref at remote 0x7fff992d81d0>) at remote 0x7fff9ac32970>, _name='TOTL_BENE_CNT', _index=<Ra
ngeIndex(_range=<range at remote 0x7ffff78007e0>, _name=...(truncated),
    locals={'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <SourceFil
eLoader(name='__main__', path='cos_sim.py') at remote 0x7ffff7800550>, '__spec__': None, '__annota
tions__': {}, '__builtins__': <module at remote 0x7ffff787b0e0>, '__file__': 'cos_sim.py', '__cach
ed__': None, 'time': <module at remote 0x7ffff7860b30>, 'pd': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e50e0>, '
np': <module at remote 0x7ffff76e5810>, 'cosine_similarity': <function at remote 0x7fff9a0d08b0>,
'path_A': '/home/gndumbri/diag.csv', 'calc_tfidf': <function at remote 0x7ffff78421f0>, 'start': <
float at remote 0x7fff9a0be250>, 'full': <DataFrame(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<BlockManager at remote 0x
7fff95b30ac0>, _item_cache={'TOTL_BENE_CNT': <Series(_is_copy=None, _mgr=<SingleBlockManager at re
mote 0x7fff99c23a00>, _item_cache={}, _attrs={}, _flags=<Flags(_allows_duplicate_labels=True, _obj
=<weakref at remote 0x7fff992d81d0>) at remote 0x7fff9ac32970>, _name='TOTL_BENE_CNT', _index=<Ran
geIndex(_range=<range at remote 0x7ffff78007e0>, _name=...(truncated), closeit=1,
    flags=0x7fffffffe2d8) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1063
#44 0x000000000067de4e in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (fp=0x95f340, filename=<optimized out>,
    closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffe2d8) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:428
#45 0x00000000006b6032 in pymain_run_file (cf=0x7fffffffe2d8, config=0x9617d0)
    at ../Modules/main.c:381
#46 pymain_run_python (exitcode=0x7fffffffe2d0) at ../Modules/main.c:606
#47 Py_RunMain () at ../Modules/main.c:685
#48 0x00000000006b63bd in Py_BytesMain (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>)
    at ../Modules/main.c:739
#49 0x00007ffff7df70b3 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4eea30 <main>, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe4b8,
    init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>,
    stack_end=0x7fffffffe4a8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#50 0x00000000005fa4de in _start () at ../Objects/bytesobject.c:2560
```

Comment: Test the same code with smaller arrays.

Comment: I did and was able to run the code without the Segmentation Fault error. The size of the array I passed was 43098 x 15497. It is giving me the Segmentation Fault error when trying an array of 86196 x 15497, which is the array I need to pass to the cosine_similarity() sklearn function. I guess, I didn't know there was a  limit (within reason) for the array size through sklearn's cosine_similarity function. Is that the case?

Comment: We get `memory error` when python code tries to make an array that's too big for available memory.  But according to your truncated traceback, the error appears to occur within a `blas` function (or on calling it).  It's in `.so`, compiled code.   A fuller traceback might give us more idea what it is doing at this point.  I haven't dug into `cosine_similarity` code, but it might be crating a large `outer` comparison between every "row" with every other "row".  For `n` rows that would be a n**2 array.

Comment: Yes exactly, it is an n^2 array, and I have added the complete traceback as an update to my post. I have seen issues like this get reported to numpy (just as an example), I am just not sure if that's the issue and I need to report an issue, or if there is something I can change about what I am doing to resolve it.